# In AWS Rekognition is it possible to identify an person in a video from an Image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-rekognition

For my current use case, I'm looking at 2 things. 1 is a video of a person. And 1 is a photo of this same person. Can AWS Rekognition help me to detect if the person in the video is the same one in the photo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Working with stored video analysis - Amazon Rekognition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/video.html):

> Amazon Rekognition Video is an API that you can use to analyze videos. With Amazon Rekognition Video, you can detect labels, faces, people, celebrities, and adult (suggestive and explicit) content in videos that are stored in an Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket. You can use Amazon Rekognition Video in categories such as media/entertainment and public safety. Previously, scanning videos for objects or people would have taken many hours of error-prone viewing by a human being. Amazon Rekognition Video automates the detection of items and when they occur throughout a video.

Rekognition allows the creation of a **Face Collection**, which is basically a set of faces learned from photos. So, you would need to:

- Create an empty Face Collection
- Provide a photo and use `IndexFaces()` to load the face from the photo into the Face Collection
- Then [Search stored videos for faces - Amazon Rekognition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/procedure-person-search-videos.html)

The output is a big JSON list of times in the video when faces from the Face Collection are found in the video (down to the millisecond).

Here's an example: [Automated video editing with YOU as the star! | AWS Machine Learning Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/automated-video-editing-with-you-as-the-star/)